# NodeJS Express app.get() not responding to call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to nodejs, and i wanted to make something like a weather app. I have file pass.txt with my api key, and i want to read this file, and then wait for get calls at api endpoint, but the app.get is behaving like there was no get call for him. after clicking the button it's console logging out my html
code. What can i do to get the api key instead of html code?

JS CODE

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')

    btn.addEventListener('click', e =>{
        
        fetch('/api')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(data =>{
            console.log(data)
        })

    })
```

nodejs

```
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs')


let port = 2932;

console.log('listening on' + port)

const key = fs.readFile('./public/pass.txt', 'utf8', (err,data) =>{
    if (err) console.log(err)

    app.get('/api', (req,res) =>{
        console.log(key)
        res.send(data)
    })

    console.log(data) // console logs the key
})


http.createServer((req,res) =>{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'})
    fs.readFile('public/index.html', (error,data) =>{
        if(error){
            res.writeHead(404)
            res.write('Files not found')
        }

        res.write(data)
        res.end()
    })
}).listen(port)
```

Comment: Why GET /api is inside the callback of readFile?

Comment: I wanted to pass the data parameter to res.send(). So it can't be in readfile cb?

Comment: Considering you're saying that it's like there's any call to GET /api... Honestly I never tried to do something like this and would amazed if it would working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering the route handler inside the readFile callback, while you most likely need to do the opposite. Also there is no need to use the low level `http` interface to setup a server taking into account that you have `express`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path');

app.get('/api', (req,res) =>{
  fs.readFile('./public/pass.txt', 'utf8', (err,data) =>{
    if (err) console.log(err)
    res.send(data)
  })
})

app.use('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'));
})

let port = 2932;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('listening on ' + port)
})
```